# Generate XML adding a custom value on a table's column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INCREMENTAL_TABLE](
    [GTIN] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PRESENTATION] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [LEVEL] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [INCREMENTAL] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_INCREMENTAL_TABLE_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GTIN] ASC,
    [PRESENTATION] ASC,
    [LEVEL] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And now, I'm creating a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @gint bigint,   
    @pres tinyint,
    @level bigint,
    @quantity smallint
AS

    DECLARE @current_incremental bigint
    DECLARE @counter bigint

    -- Get current incremental.
    set @current_incremental = 
        (SELECT INCREMENTAL
            FROM INCREMENTAL_TABLE
            WHERE GTIN = @gint AND
              PRESENTATION = @pres AND
              LEVEL = @level)

    -- 
    SET @counter = @current_incremental
    WHILE ((@counter - @current_incremental) <= @quantity)
        BEGIN

            SET @counter = @counter + 1
        END


GO
```

Inside this stored procedure I have to create a XML with `@quantity` nodes. Imagine I have this call:

```
EXEC MyProc @gint = 1 @pres = 2 @level = 3 @quantity = 100
```

And, I have this initial value:

```
@current_incremental = 10
```

With these data, I have to return a xml with these values:

```
GTIN | PRESENTATION | LEVEL | INCREMENTAL
-----+--------------+-------+------------
  1  |       2      |   3   |    10
-----+--------------+-------+------------
  1  |       2      |   3   |    11
-----+--------------+-------+------------
  1  |       2      |   3   |    12

[ ... ]
-----+--------------+-------+------------
  1  |       2      |   3   |    109
```

But I'm not going to insert it into the table.

**How can I get a XML with these data if I can't do it with a select to that table?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified [Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22863412/68571) to fit my needs:

```
declare @gint bigint = 1;
declare @pres tinyint = 2;
declare @level bigint = 3;
declare @quantity smallint = 100;
declare @current_incremental bigint = 20000000;

with Numbers as
(
  select row_number() over(order by 1/0) as N
  from sys.all_objects as o1 cross join
       sys.all_objects as o2
)
select @gint as GINT,
       @pres as PRESENTATION,
       @level as LEVEL,
       N + @current_incremental as INCREMENTAL
from Numbers
where N < @quantity
for xml path('row'), root('root'), type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a numbers table or some other table with enough rows in it.

```sql
declare @gint int = 1;
declare @pres int = 2;
declare @level int = 3;
declare @quantity int = 100;
declare @current_incremental int = 10;

with Numbers as
(
  select row_number() over(order by 1/0) as N
  from sys.all_objects as o1 cross join
       sys.all_objects as o2
)
select @gint as GINT,
       @pres as PRESENTATION,
       @level as LEVEL,
       N as INCREMENTAL
from Numbers
where N >= @current_incremental and
      N < @current_incremental + @quantity
for xml path('row'), root('root'), type
```

Result:

```xml
<root>
  <row>
    <GINT>1</GINT>
    <PRESENTATION>2</PRESENTATION>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <INCREMENTAL>10</INCREMENTAL>
  </row>
  <row>
    <GINT>1</GINT>
    <PRESENTATION>2</PRESENTATION>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <INCREMENTAL>11</INCREMENTAL>
  </row>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <row>
    <GINT>1</GINT>
    <PRESENTATION>2</PRESENTATION>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <INCREMENTAL>108</INCREMENTAL>
  </row>
  <row>
    <GINT>1</GINT>
    <PRESENTATION>2</PRESENTATION>
    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
    <INCREMENTAL>109</INCREMENTAL>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question: What is `Numbers`? Is it the number table?

Comment: @VansFannel Numbers in my answer is a CTE that is instead of a numbers table. The CTE uses a cross join between two fairly large tables to give enough rows. If you don't want to use the CTE you can create a numbers table of your own that only has one column numbered from 1 (or 0) to however many rows you need.

Comment: @VansFannel More info on a numbers table [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: If I use `declare @current_incremental bigint = 2000000;` it doesn't work. `@quantity` is the number of rows that I need. And the `INCREMENTAL` will have these values: from 2000000 to 2000099.

Comment: @VansFennel I see you have figures it out. You just have to treat the numbers a bit differently.